# VBA error: Application defined or object defined error

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I am getting this error in excel: application defined of object defined error

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
b = 1

Set r2 = Range("a1:a100")

For Each r1 In r2.Cells
   If r1.Value = "hummer1" Then
    a = r1.Row
    Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 5)).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 1)).Paste    "line with the error"
    b = b + 1
   End If
Next r1

End Sub
```

it looks very simple but I was unable to figure out what is the problem

Comment: is the range getting copied?

Comment: yes, its getting copied

Comment: Should `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 1)).Paste` not be `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 5)).Paste`?

Comment: I don't think `("Sheet2").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 5)).Paste`  would make any difference, well but I tried it and its not working

Comment: try `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1)).Paste`

Comment: After putting `Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1)).Paste`  it throws a new error "Object dosen't support this property or method"

Comment: Assuming sheet1 is active, you need to do `sheets ("sheet2").range(cells(b,1).address).paste`.

Comment: use `PasteSpecial` instead of `Paste`

Comment: No. The problem is unqualified `cells` object which refers to the active sheet while trying to define a range on another sheet. ...

Comment: Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(b, 1).paste would so the trick too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to mention worksheets to have clear code. The following works provided you do not use formula and do not want updates on the second worksheet:

```
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
b = 1
Dim wkSheet1 As Worksheet
Dim wkSheet2 As Worksheet

Set wkSheet1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wkSheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set r2 = wkSheet1.Range("a1:a100")

For Each r1 In r2.Cells
  If r1.Value = "hummer1" Then
    a = r1.Row
    wkSheet1.Range(wkSheet1.Cells(a, 1), wkSheet1.Cells(a, 5)).Copy
    wkSheet2.Range(wkSheet2.Cells(b, 1), wkSheet2.Cells(b, 5)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    b = b + 1
  End If
Next r1
```

By the way, use "worksheets" instead of "sheets": sheets object points to both graphic sheets and usual sheets. Since you know you want to paste on a usual sheet, mentionning it make the code more readable!

Comment: Thanks, Although I tried `Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(b, 1), Sheet2.Cells(b, 1))`  before but the thing that I was missing was `PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`, thats why it wasn't working

Answer (score 0):

No way to check but I think `Paste` method is available on `Worksheets Object` only.
So to make it work remove it and execute direct copy like this:

```
Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 5)).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 1))
```

Also, since `r2` is declared as `Range` object, your `For Each Loop` should be as simple as:

```
For Each r1 In r2
    '~~> rest of code here
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
b = 1

Set r2 = Range("a1:a100")

For Each r1 In r2.Cells
If r1.Value = "hummer1" Then
a = r1.Row
Range(Cells(a, 1), Cells(a, 5)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & b)
b = b + 1
End If
Next r1

End Sub
```